# How to prevent android activity from opening from the background?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I am using Firebase as a Backend database in my project. As I open some other app whenenver there is a change in firebase database my app will be displayed in the foreground. How can I fix that issue. I have this issue working on multiple users. If one user is using my app then he has no issue. But if multiple users use my app then that issue occurs.

```
  myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Database")
            .child("DriverConfirm");

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(PassengerConfirmScreen.this, "ERROR: " + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code, that would be helpful.

Comment: I have added the code in my question section. Because I added addValueEventListener whenever there is a change in the database the app will resume from the background.

Comment: @deepakkumar I have added the code in my question. Please go through it once

Comment: Are you removing the listener in onDestroy() method by using myRef.removeEventListener(listener)